# What CSS property to make items not stack?

Tags: html, css, drupal

I am trying to align the elements shown in the below picture in the following way. I want the slideshow image to be where it is now, the title link where it is now, but I want the description text to be below the title and aligned next to the slideshow image, not have the div stack behind it.

Does anyone know an element that I can put on the slideshow image (with the green border) in order for this item to not allow the div to stack behind it?

The title of this below has a float:left on it which is making it appear next to the slideshow, but then the description text below, when I put a float:left on it, it goes next to the title.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer just came to me like the CSS gods said hey bro its so obvious as I was typing the last part of the question.

In order to make the div stack below the picture, I had to make the "title" div extend to end of the container, so the description div below, automatically stacked below it when i floated it left of the image.

As you can see by the borders, I made the title long enough so the description div would automatically goto the next line. Durrrr. Not sure if anyone cares, but I all ready wrote the whole question out so maybe someone will search it and find it useful. This was with views slideshow with drupal, so it can be confusing sometimes.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

on the title, add a small css code ex.

```
.left {
float: left
}
```

add also a clear class

```
.clear {
clear: both
}
```

And in your html code, use this

```
<img />
<h1 class="left">Title</h1>
<div class="clear"></div>
<p>Description</p>
```